Relation between infinite Taylor series and root of a function
[I'm following Time Series Analysis and Its Applications, 4th edition, by Robert H. Shumway and David S. Stofer, link, part 3.1]
An AR(p) model is one that can be written as:
$$\color{red}{(1-\phi_1B-\phi_2B^2-...-\phi_pB^p)}x_t =w_t \\
\color{red}{\phi(B)}x_t=w_t
$$
Where B is the backshift operator ($Bx_t=x_{t-1}$), and $\phi(B)$ is shorthand for $(1-\phi_1 B-...)$.
An AR model is causal if it can be written as the infinite sum of previous noises (Definition 3.7):
$$ x_t = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\psi_jw_{t-j}, \; \;w_{t-j}\sim wn(0,\sigma^2)
$$
And we also require that $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}|\psi_j|<\infty$ (I'm assuming for the series not to explode, and for it to converge in the mean-square).
To get these $\psi$ coefficients we replace $x_t$ with the operator version of it:
$$ \color{red}{(1-\phi_1B-\phi_2B^2-...-\phi_pB^p)}\color{purple}{(1+\psi_1 B+\psi_2B^2 +...)}w_t =w_t \\
\color{red}{\phi(B)}\color{purple}{\psi(B)}w_t=w_t
$$
We get that $\phi(B)\psi(B)=1$, and treating these as polynomials (replacing $B$ with some complex number $z$) we can divide by $\phi(z)$ and get
$$\psi(z)=1/\phi(z)$$
First, this looks to me like the left hand side is an infinite Taylor series expansion of the right hand side, around $z=0$. Is that correct?
The book mentions that the process is causal when the roots of the polynomial lie outside the unit circle, that is $|r_i| > 1,\;\; \forall \phi(r_i)=0$. Why is it so? What is the relation between the infinite series $\psi(z)$ and the roots of $\phi(z)$?

I think the reason being is that the Taylor series on the left side converges only for $|z|<1$:
$$ \psi(z) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \psi_j z^j = \frac{1}{\phi(z)} = \frac{1}{1-\phi_1z-\phi_2z^2-...-\phi_pz^p}
$$
And so we demand that for this range, there are not roots for $\phi(z)$ on the right side.
